# Deny file access but server properly in IIS

Tags: security, iis

I have a js file that includes in the master page.

I want to deny the file access when user type the direct link in the browser address bar.

I've tried the URL filtering IIS,like:

```
<security>
        <requestFiltering>
            <denyUrlSequences>
                <add sequence="Scripts/Foo/bar.min.js" />
            </denyUrlSequences>
        </requestFiltering>
    </security>
```

This does work, when i type 'localhost://blah/Scripts/Foo/bar.min.js' I get blocked.

**but the page whitch need this js file can not render.**

Does anyone have a workaround? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3):

I finnaly found [this](http://www.iis.net/configreference/system.webserver/security/requestfiltering/filteringrules/filteringrule/appliesto).

and added these sections to web.config:

```
<security>
  <requestFiltering>
    <filteringRules>
      <filteringRule name="protectjs" scanUrl="true" scanQueryString="true">
        <scanHeaders>
          <clear />
          <add requestHeader="Accept" />
        </scanHeaders>
        <appliesTo>
          <clear />
          <add fileExtension=".js" />
        </appliesTo>
        <denyStrings>
          <clear />
          <add string="text/html" />
        </denyStrings>
      </filteringRule>
    </filteringRules>
  </requestFiltering>
</security>
```

It works at present, though I know this way is not that reliable.

Comment: Works perfectly for PHP, too! Could you explain how this works?

Answer (score 2):

Not 100% sure but I don’t think there is a way to do this. When browser renders your page it actually sends the same request to the server as the one you do when you manually type in JS file in the browser.

IIS doesn’t have means to distinguish requests you make and the one browser makes in the background while processing your page.

One thing that might work is

1. adding some kind of ID to your JS file like this Scripts/Foo/bar.min.js?ID=E3CF305B-4444-E011-8FD2-1CC1DEE89A7F
2. ID is time limited and works only 20 seconds or so after it’s created (enough time for browser to load the page)
3. creating  custom handler that will parse ID and decide if server should return the request or not

So when someone types Scripts/Foo/bar.min.js handler will reject the request but it will also reject request when expired ID is used.

However this is most probably going to be difficult to maintain and also performance intensive for your server.

If you want to hide your JS file why not obfuscate it.

Comment: Thanks your answer. I worked this out and I will post the result to this question.

Answer (score 0):

Use HttpModule and Check for HttpContext.Current.Request.UrlReferrer. it will always be null for direct access to the .js file.

```
public class JSAccessModule : IHttpModule
{
    public void Init(System.Web.HttpApplication Appl)
    {
        Appl.BeginRequest += new System.EventHandler(Rewrite_BeginRequest);
    }

    public void Rewrite_BeginRequest(object sender, System.EventArgs args)
    {
        //Block if direct Url is accessed
        if (HttpContext.Current.Request.UrlReferrer == null)
        {
            HttpApplication App = (HttpApplication)sender;
            string path = App.Request.Path;

            string strExt = System.IO.Path.GetExtension(path);
            if (strExt == ".js")
            {
                HttpContext.Current.Response.Redirect("~/AccessDenied.html");
            }
        }
    }

    public void Dispose() { }
}
```